# Change of variable integration question $(x,y) \to (u,v)$

Tags: calculus, integration

This is the question I need confirmation with

[image]

My final answer was $1/2$ using $u=x^2$ and $v=y^2$. I am pretty sure it is incorrect so would like the most simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try with $u = xy$, $v = x/y$.
EDIT:
The Jacobian is:
$$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} =
\left|
\begin{matrix}
y & x\\
1/y & -x/y^2\\
\end{matrix}
\right| = -\frac{2x}y = -2v,
$$
and by the inverse function theorem:
$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = - \frac1{2v}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I chose to use v = y/x instead which got me 45/32 as the v = x/y brought me a negative result which was -45/32. Assuming all was done correctly, would both be correct? Can anyone confirm the answer for me with a solution if possible?

Comment: @user112817, surely you have forgotten taking the absolute value of Jacobian.

Comment: Determinant of the Jacobian you mean? I did that. My delta(x,y)/delta(u,x) = 1/(2*v)

Comment: @user112817, see the edit.

Comment: I see where I have gone wrong. So both choices of (u,v) would have been the same had I taken the absolute of the Jacobian. I did not know that we had to take the absolute of Jacobian. Never been placed in the situation where it was needed.